# Static IP after reboot conflict with repository : [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try

Tags: dhcp, centos7, repository, static-ip

I install *CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611* on vmware. In the first part, after enabled dhclient I can install and download using commands but I set static IP to avoid to use dhclient command every after reboot.
But after reboot commands like

```
yum install wget
```

return me errors like this

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=x86_6     4&repo=os&infra=stock error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org;
```

or also

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl     #6 - "Could not resolve host: mirror.centos.org;
```

It works only if I change

```
BOOTPROTO=static
```

into

```
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
```

but why I can't no set a static IP ?

After installed on vmware, I choose bridge mode and I follow this commands to set correctly IP but after reboot something should be wrong
This is what I did

```
systemctl status NetworkManager
nmcli d
```

> ens33 --> ethernet name

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
dhclient
ip addr show
```

> 192.168.1.6 --> IP
>   192.168.1.255 --> broadcast

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
cat ifcfg-ens33

yum provides ifconfig
yum install net-tools
ifconfig -a

    ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.6  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe1b:749f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:1b:74:9f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 223  bytes 20753 (20.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 155  bytes 37073 (36.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 588  bytes 50868 (49.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 588  bytes 50868 (49.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


yum install nano
```

Now I use *putty*

```
cd /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/
nano ifcfg-ens33
```

I edit so

```
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.1.6
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME=ens33
UUID=b7982a78-da67-487f-bca9-3adec9dec4e2
DEVICE=ens33
ONBOOT=yes

systemctl restart network
ip add
ping 8.8.8.8
```

*packets received*

I check if interface is on

```
systemctl start NetworkManager
nmcli d
```

green -> connected

I kill dhclient

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
ps -ef | grep dhclient
```

I see processes like this

```
root      10217      1  0 12:32 ?        00:00:00 dhclient
root      10790  10299  0 12:43 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto dhclient
```

I kill 10217 process

```
kill 10217
ps -ef | grep dhclient
```

then

```
systemctl restart network
systemctl start NetworkManager
reboot
```

enter again, user/password

```
nmcli d
systemctl status NetworkManager
```

is ok and active

now and only now I can reconnect with putty

I type

```
yum install wget
```

but return me errors like `Could not retrieve mirrorlist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be because you didn't configure a DNS server to use.

The key is this line `14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org;`

It seems your DHCP server was pushing both a default and a set of DNS server, and by using a static config, you are no longer getting the DNS servers (you configured the default route, so don't need that, though).

Your best bet may be to edit the same file you did previously (`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ens33`), and add:

```
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

Or adjust the lines above to suit your own setup.